# git tfs clone in Cygwin does nothing

Tags: git, tfs, cygwin, git-tfs

I have installed GitTfs 0.15.0 and am trying to clone under Cygwin.  I've done the following:

- Extracted into a directory, GitTfs-0.15.0
- chmod +x for every file in GitTfs-0.15.0
- Added GitTfs-0.15.0 to the front of my path
- Verified that which git-tfs finds git-tfs.exe

Now I am trying to clone our project, and I get nothing:

```
git tfs clone http://tfshost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection '$/Project/branch'
```

I am pretty sure I have these details correct (the same details worked in the TFS plugin for Eclipse).  But when I run this git tfs clone command, I get nothing.  The command immediately exits, and the exit status is 0.  There is no output.

How can I troubleshoot what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

git-tfs is not standalone.  In addition to extracting it and putting it in your path, you need .NET 4 and either the 2008 or 2010 version of Team Explorer installed.  And it clearly says so on the git-tfs.com homepage, so I'm not sure how I missed that.

I did learn that there is a -d option that can be passed to git-tfs to get some debugging information.  I also learned, by doing a strace from cygwin, that there were needed .NET libraries that I did not have.